# Creating a MongoDB collection in pymongo with the name of the collection based on an element from a stringarray

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, twitter, pymongo

Im new to python so go easy on me! I am trying to implement a stream listener via tweepy that streams tweets based on a filter of keywords (used an array of strings for this) and save these tweets to a collection in a mongodb (using pymongo).

I have been successful in doing this but now I want to take this further by saving a tweet filtered by a specific string from my filterKeywords array to a mongodb collection named after the string element of the array that it was filtered by (ie a tweet filtered by the string element 'Apple' to be saved into a mongodb collection called 'Apple'.

I have tried to do this already with no luck via an for loop in the on_data method to cycle through the array and an if an element is found within a tweet then attempt to create a collection based on that keyword element but it simply creates a collection called 'word' and saves it to that.

Here is my code below (ive left out my twitter auth credentials for obvious reasons). Hopefully someone can help

```
import tweepy
import pymongo
import json

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filterKeywords = ['IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Apple', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'EBay', 'Diageo',
                   'General Motors', 'General Electric', 'Telefonica', 'Rolls Royce', 'Walmart', 'HSBC', 'BP',
                   'Investec', 'WWE', 'Time Warner', 'Santander Group']


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()

        self.db = pymongo.MongoClient().mydb


    def on_data(self, tweet):
        data = json.loads(tweet)
        for word in filterKeywords:
            if word in data:
                collection = self.db[word]
                collection.insert(data),
        print (tweet)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        return True # Don't kill the stream


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(track=filterKeywords)
```

Comment: Something like `db[word]` where `word` is a variable with value `"IBM"` will access a collection called `IBM` just fine for me. What happens if, as a test, you replace `word` with a string literal like `"cookies"`?

Comment: I thought that too but it doesnt do that for me. I also tried replacing it with a string (used "cookies" like you suggested) and now it not even creating any collection, even when I revert the code to above. It must be something simple that I'm missing here. Ill have another look to see why my code stopped creating collections full stop

Comment: Ok it seems to me that my if statement just doesnt work at all, when I remove it, and use a string literal as suggested it works 

`def on_data(self, tweet):
        data = json.loads(tweet)
        collection = db["cookies"]
        collection.insert(data),
        print (tweet)`

Is there a concise way of doing this rather than writing 20 case statements? I just think thats a poor way to code that and it means that if any changes need made I may have to make the change 20 times rather than once.

Comment: Is it the if statement not working the way you expect, perhaps? You should be able to do things dynamically like you want. What is the value of `data`?

Comment: Yea it looks to be that way. The value of data will be the current json object pulled from the tweepy stream listener, so it changes every time a new tweet is pulled from the stream.

Comment: Ok after some debugging there, Ive figured out its to do with the fact that the `data` variable is not being populated meaning the if statement within the for loop is being made redundant. Ill work on that today and see if that fixes my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this fixed from an answer to another question that I asked, my pymongo code actually worked it was to do with me loading the tweets into JSON format. This then required a 'key' check for a 'text' key then to check if that text contained one of my filterKeyword. Here is the updated on_data method

```
def on_data(self, data):
datajson = json.loads(data)
for word in filterKeywords:
    if datajson.get('text') and word in datajson['text']:
        collection = db[word]
        collection.insert(datajson)
        print('Tweet found filtered by ' + word)
```